# Foundation 5 - remove / over write CSS thumbnail image blue hover effect

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation 5 and am really struggling finding the CSS I need to customise it. There are plenty of SCSS examples of how to overwrite defaults but not nothing of the CSS.  I am using firebug to try and get the styles used to overwrite but it's really difficult.

At the moment I am stuck trying to change the blue mouseover effect on the images in thumbnails. I would like to replace the colour, or remove this affect completely. I have tried different variations of the below the below:

```
a.th:hover  {
    border: none;
}

a.th img {
    border:  none;
    outline:  none;
}


<article class="large-3 small-6 columns product-box">
    <a class="th" href="#"><img src="images/denim_jacket.jpg"></a>
    <div class="panel">
        <h5><a href="#">Levi´s Blue Denim</a></h5>
        <span class="price">£40.00</span>
    </div>
</article>
```

I've taken the code from the following page:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/thumbnails.html

Comment: Can you post the HTML? Specifically the rendered DOM and potentially whatever all has been applied to the classes you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code below is the original css values. You can change it to suit your desired effect.

```
a.th:hover, a.th:focus {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(0, 140, 186, 0.5);
 box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(0, 140, 186, 0.5);
}
```